# "And" & "Or" SharePoint Filters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, data-view-web-part

Does anybody know the logic behind the "And" & "Or" functions in SharePoint 2013? Specifically dealing with the view filters behind List Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heavy subject!

Not going to try to explain it because this gentleman excelled at it:

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/11/understanding-filters-in-sharepoint-list-views-aspx/

Just 2 general tips:

- Remember that the conditions in operators are grouped from the beginning.
- Operators are taking effect between all conditions on the left of the filter and the single next condition.

Cheers!

Comment: Very Heavy! It took me awhile to find out there was a logic behind these functions but I'm glad you shared this article.

Comment: Apparently, the site is down. Could someone up its content?

Comment: As good as it gets:

https://wordpress.training-nyc.com/sharepoint-training/understanding-filters-sharepoint-list-views-solved/

Best